# Why is my PHP echo returning a 0 in some places (yet working in others)?

Tags: php, jquery, concatenation

When a form submits, the AJAX code below replaces anything with id = `levelreplace` with the word in the char column titled `level` in the MYSQL database. (For reference, the word in this column is "**Easy**.")

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({  
            url :  "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $(".levelreplace").text(data.level);   
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I also have this bit of JQuery which is supposed to take a div with id = `classadderpanel` and append the class "**Easy**" (using the AJAX above).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#classadderpanel').addClass('<?php  echo "<span class='levelreplace'>" + $data['level'] + "</span>"; ?>');      
});
</script>
```

However, instead of adding the class "**Easy**" it adds the class "**0**". I know that there's nothing wrong with the AJAX returning the correct MYSQL data because, elsewhere, I have the code:

```
<?php echo "<span class='wordlevelreplace'>" .$data['WordLevel']."</span>"; ?>
```

...and that successfully echoes the word "**Easy**."

I'm guessing this has something to do with either my quotes or my concatenation, but I've played around with every iteration that I can think of and the problem does not resolve.

Full code (only with components relevant to the problem):

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

//AJAX to replace everything with id = "levelreplace" with the word in MYSQL column "level"

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({  
            url :  "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $(".levelreplace").text(data.level);        
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>

//Code to add class equal to the word in column titled "level" 

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#classadderpanel').addClass('<?php  echo "<span class='levelreplace'>" + $data['level'] + "</span>"; ?>'); // Returns 0     
});
</script>

</head>

// ECHO SHOWING THAT THE AJAX SOMETIMES RETURN THE WORD "EASY" IN THE COLUMN LEVEL...AND SOMETIMES IT DOESN'T 

<?php
echo "<span class='levelreplace'>" .$data['level']."</span>"; //Returns Easy;  This is how I want everything with class = "levelrelace" to get replaced
?>

// DIV THAT SHOULD HAVE THE CLASS ADDED
<div id="classadderpanel" style="background-color: orange;">
<form id ="form" class = "classtest" action="aplayground_classadderform.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit"  >
</div>


</html>
```

Comment: Where is `test.php`?

Comment: Why are you passing a DOM Node to `addClass` ( `echo "<span class=...` ) ? `addClass` can either take a class name (string) or a function as argument.

Comment: isn't the echo containing the 0 using + vs . syntax?

Comment: External. It's definitely not an issue of returning the data because `<?php echo "<span class='levelreplace'>" .$data['level']."</span>";
?>` returns the word "Easy" from the column titled 'level'.

Comment: The problem is that the line before that is using `+` instead of `.`. This converts all the strings to numbers, and they all convert to 0, so it echoes `0`.

Comment: @Adrianopolis Yes, but the issue is within the JQuery:    `$('#classadderpanel').addClass('<?php  echo "<span class='levelreplace'>" + $data['level'] + "</span>"; ?>'); // Returns 0     
});`   I thought you have to use + to concatenate in Javascript/Jquery? I've tried replacing the pluses here with decimals and it still returns `0`

Comment: Hey Be Bo... just for grins what happens if you do this in your js: var my_class = <?php echo $data['WordLevel'] ?>;

Comment: @Adrianopolis If I do that, though, the AJAX code wouldn't add the class immediately on form submit without refreshing the page because there wouldn't be anything with class = "levelreplace"

Answer (score 1):

You are using JS Syntax in your php on this line:

```
$('#classadderpanel').addClass('<?php  echo "<span class='levelreplace'>" + $data['level'] + "</span>"; ?>');
```

It should be:

```
$('#classadderpanel').addClass('<?php  echo "<span class='levelreplace'>" . $data['level'] . "</span>"; ?>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response; I've tried that, though, and that line then returns the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function`

Comment: To give you some further info: it returns `$('#classadderpanel').addClass('<span class='wordlevelreplace'>Easy</span>'); `  so the span needs to be stripped. I can't figure out how to do that though; escaping with backslashes in front of each single quote doesn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The string (produced by PHP) `<span class='levelreplace'>Easy</span>` just **cannot** be a valid `class` to add to the element `$('#classadderpanel')`.
This method expects a string, not an element.

I can't say where the zero comes from...

But I think you want to add a `span` to the `div`.
So just use `.append()` or `.prepend()` instead of `.addClass()`.

That *probably* is what you are looking for.

**Or** just add the `span` using PHP !
Because I don't know what can be the use to make it on client-side on document ready.

---

Why not just to this and forget about appending with jQuery?

```
<div id="classadderpanel" style="background-color: orange;">
  <span class='levelreplace'><?php echo $data['level']; ?></span>
  <form id="form" class="classtest" action="aplayground_classadderform.php" method="POST">
  <input type="submit">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting idea. However, when I replace `addClass` with `append` as follows: `$('#classadderpanel').append("<span class='levelreplace'>" . $data['level'] . "</span>"; ?>');` I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function" at that line.

Comment: In the console's command line, please type `$.fn.jquery` and post the result.

Comment: Okay, So this means jQuery is loaded. Check if the opening PHP tag is there... `<?php echo ...`. An incorrect string passed as argument *could* be the cause of the error. I would suggest `$('#classadderpanel').append("<span class='levelreplace'><?php echo $data['level']; ?></span>");`

Comment: I think we're getting closer but it still returns the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function" at that line. It now returns `$('#classadderpanel').append("<span class='levelreplace'>Easy</span>");` Even when I try using `$('#classadderpanel').addClass("Test");` I get the same error; it's bizarre, almost as though there's something wrong with `$('#classadderpanel')`

Comment: Another great suggestion, but I don't think that will work in my case. I'll explain exactly what I'm trying to do; slightly different from code above because I tried to simplify. When the form is submitted, I want anything with a class equal to the word in the column "WordLevel" to have the class "Active" added. (.Active has unique CSS properties). Ex: If WordLevel column has the entry "Easy", any div with class = "Easy" will have the class "Active" added so that it will take on those CSS properties.

Comment: Within the AJAX command, I tried to use `$('.<?php  echo "<span class='wordlevelreplace'>" + $data['WordLevel'] + "</span>"; ?>').addClass("Active");` but it returns `$('.0').addClass("Active");` I need it to return `$('.Easy').addClass("Active");`

Comment: mmm... It looks like a weird mix. Please show all your real code. We'll save time here.

Comment: Here's the complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/zcvrwcws/    The AJAX/Jquery snippet in question is in line 93

Comment: Ok... About line #93. it should be `$('.<?php  echo $data['WordLevel']; ?>').addClass("Active");` and the `div` at line #221 should be hidden on load if `$data['WordLevel']` contains the string "Easy".

Comment: I suggest you clean your code from all the "tests" you've made... Group the `<style>` and `<script>` tags toguether... About JS, groups the "ready" wrapper toguether in `head` and same in `body`... Ho! wait! there is no `<body>` tag! Look for the basic HTML too! Clean that! If it is easier for others to read it... It it be for YOU too. ;) **Please, [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) your code**

Comment: I made the obvious in this [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/kqe5DBki)... I fixed the "line #93" (which is not line #93 now). Start from this. ;)

Comment: And... By the way, what is `jquery.max.js` ? Why "max"? Did you tweak it? And, most importantly, is that a second jQuery library loaded? You can't use two!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me; I appreciate it as I'm trying my best to self-teach...which explains the horrible formatting. Sorry about that! `jquery.max.js` is a vestige from a previous code I had been testing. Your suggestion to change (formerly) line 93 to `$('.<?php echo $data['WordLevel']; ?>').addClass("Active");` works but the only problem is that it only adds the class on page refresh. I'm trying to use the AJAX to change this as soon as the form is submitted, which is why I had those spans in there. Is there a way to tweak accordingly?

Comment: Put the same exact line in the `success` callback of the ajax... It will work too.

Comment: I tried it `success: function (data) {
$(".wordlevelreplace").text(data.wordlevel); 
$(".incorrectanswermark").fadeIn('slow');   
   $('.<?php echo $data['WordLevel']; ?>').addClass("Active");    
            },`  and it does add the class but only after page refresh

Comment: Try `$(document).find('.<?php echo $data['WordLevel']; ?>').addClass("Active");` in the `success` callback... Maybe. -- To add `$(document).find()` will ensure to target the elements even if they are dynamically created via Ajax.